# Find all the continuous functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ a continuous  function such that for all $x \in [0,1]$ we have that $f(f(x))=x$. Find all the function that acomplish this.

Because is continuous in $[0,1]$ we have that $f$ have for maximum $1$ and minimum $0$.
We have that $f(f(x))=x$, so if $f(x)=y$ then $f(y)=x$ ant his make $f$ injective, because if $f(z)=y$ then $f(f(z))=x \neq z$.

So, $f$ is continous and one-to-one then $f$ is strictly monotone. If $f(1)=z$ for some $z \in [0,1) $ we have that $f(z)=1$ and we conclude that $f$ is strictly decreasing. In other hand, if $f(0)= w$ for some $w \in (0,1]$ we have that $f(w)=0$, and we conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing and this is a contradiction, then $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, and with this $f$ is stictly  increasing. And then there is only one function that acomplish the past statments  $f(x)=x$.

Am I right?

Comment: Or $f(x) = 1-x$... or $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

Comment: Are there any other continuous involutions on $[0,1]$?

Comment: " In other hand, if f(0)=w for some w∈(0,1] we have that f(w)=0, and we conclude that f is strictly increasing"  Would we concluse $f$ is strictly *decreasing*.  After all $f(w) = 0 < f(0)$.  So that's not a contradicition.  And indeed $f(x) = 1-x$ is a function where $f(f(x) = 1-(1-x)= x$.

Comment: yeah, you're right, so is better to think like there are tiw differents cases?, when $f$ is increasing and decreasing?

Comment: "and with this f is stictly increasing. And then there is only one function that acomplish the past statments f(x)=x"  are you claiming $f(x) =x$ is the *only* strictly increasing continuous function where $f(0) =0$ and $f(1) = 1$?  You ought to realize that is nonsense.  We have the endpoints are equal, and we know it can't "double back" but it can do anything else in between.  $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[5] x$ and $f(x)=\sin (\frac \pi 2 x)$ all are continuous strictly increasing and have $f(0)=0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: @fleablood but we are looking that $f(f(x))=x$, $f(x)=x^{2}$ doesn't do this for example.

Comment: Did I ever say it *did*? I'm esponding to your claim "then f(0)=0 and f(1)=1, and with this f is stictly increasing. ... There is only one function that acomplish the past statments f(x)=x". That is just wrong as my examples show.  You've only used the property $f(f(x))=x$ to show that $f$ is strictly monotonic and (incorrectly) that $f(0) = 0; f(1) =1$.  That is certainly *not* enough to show $f(x)=x$. There're *infinitely* many functions so that $f(0)=0;f(1)=1$ that are continuous and mono increasing. You will have to show $f(f(x))=x$ implies *more* that just that as that's not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume $f$ is monotone increasing, then there's only one function, as you've found: $f(x) = x$.

If you allow $f$ to be monotone decreasing, then there's many, many more.  In particular, let $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ denote **any** strictly decreasing continuous function with $g(0) = 1$.  Then define $$f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x), & \text{ if } g(x) \geq x \\ g^{-1}(x), & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

*On one minor abuse of notation*: It may be the case that $g$ is not surjective, hence not invertible, but this doesn't matter.  The only $x$-values at which we're evaluating $g^{-1}$ are those values such that $g(x) < x\leq 1$, and all of these are in the range of $g$ by the intermediate value property.

Comment: Given the examples $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{1-x^n}$, I wonder whether all the decreasing examples could be expressed as a conjugate of $x \mapsto 1 - x$ by some automorphism of $[0, 1]$...

Comment: I have a question, Why  $g$ has an inverse?

Comment: @mari because it's strictly decreasing and continuous, therefore 1-1 over its domain.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Is really $f(x)=x$ the only fuction that is strictly increasing? the comments above in the question says that maybe there are more functions, but i don't really see why.

Comment: @Mari As fleablood pointed out, they're not saying that there's more continuous, strictly increasing bijections $[0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$.  They're effectively just saying that you can't remove $f(f(x)) = x$ from that list of conditions.

Comment: so, how can I do it  correctly?

Comment: @Mari Suppose $f$ is strictly increasing, $f(f(x)) = x$ and $f(x) \neq x$ for some $x$.  Then there's some $a \in [0,1]$ such that $f(a) \neq a$.  Then $f(a) < a \iff a = f(f(a)) < f(a)$.

Comment: I meant an automorphism in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Actually I misread "conjugate" as "composition".  That fix changes it to be much more interesting.  I don't know if it's true, but it's certainly not trivial